# unable to generate git credential for Azure Repos git using Azure DevOps

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-repos, git-credential-manager

While clicking the button to generate git credentials under Azure DevOps, the option is loading with an anonymous exception, and the git credentials are not getting generated for a particular AD User.

How can I get past this error?

Comment: Or generate a Personal Access Token with the Code (read & Write) permission. The git credentials with username & password are no longer the recommended way to access Azure DevOps. If you install Git Credentials Manager Core, is will do this on your behalf. Your admin can disable basic auth and personal access tokens for the organisation, in which case you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

This is an known issue reported in this Azure DevOps event: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/282616310

Our engineers are still working on this event, and they have taken some measures to improve things. You can follow this event to get the latest update for it.

When you click the "**Generate Git Credentials**" button, it essentially generates a PAT (Personal Access Token) with the scope "**`Code (Read & write)`**" for your account.

So, if the issue still exists on your side, as a workaround, you can try to manually create a PAT with the scope "**`Code (Read & write)`**" for your account.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation specifies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops#use-credential-managers-to-generate-tokens)

> The Git Credential Manager is an optional tool that makes it easy to create PATs when you're working with Azure Repos. Sign in to the web portal, generate a token, and then use the token as your password when you're connecting to Azure Repos.
>
> **PATs are generated on demand when you have the credential manager installed.
>
> The credential manager creates the token in Azure DevOps and saves it locally for use with the Git command line or other client**.

So make sure you have:

- the [latest Git for Windows installed](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)
- a PATH with `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` (it is where `git-credential-manager-core.exe` resides)